# Intellij Idea deploy to tomcat generated css by sass file watcher

Tags: intellij-idea

Desired behavior:
 - I save sass file
 - sass file is compiled to css
 - css file is updated/deployed to server(tomcat)

How it works now:
 - I save sass file
 - sass file is compiled to css
 - css file is updated/deployed to server(tomcat) only if I open updated css file or I sync it manualy

How can I automate that process?

Comment: Have you got the run configuration set up to redeploy resources on frame deactivation?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is that I edit sass files, which are compiled into css files, which are closed. And as you know on frame deactivation redeploy only active frames.